# How to correctly implement function wrapper in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

**TL; DR;**

Why do I get [this error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCBDANrgI2wGMBrOAXzgDMoIQ4ByKdEmRgbgCguB6XuJnogIAOzjBRMdFGol0XdAA9IsCVJlzi6OAEFkMABYAFbFGwhUiLnFtwYEUulEAuOKhhRJAc24Ue-HAAqjDAuDTIosShYvYQcMRiAG4y8NgGhtDAAF7oACZwIOhGEAUOcJmOfAK2LDDIUKI+CQ1e+YXFmQUA7sBGcU7iiaKoyEUFtPQJYtJKMFyS0rLycMZeSdjSALKdpQA8ACqm5pZwytKieVb6RscWqAA0cAcASuijuDAAfNZ2cAAUYDM9zcR2BlgAlKC3h8YH4eItNCsAMroYgNfI7Ep5Q53U7nZxXPQZPGPZ4w5CfH4IGx2QHg1BuACiSmIuGQeXQuIZTxuJgZXyh5PelLhXH8XGokWiwFixBYm3QfKyuTyWK6AAkII49rTbGCTlYCZdriSeXrhbCuF9-haiti3GtgBttrscQb7k9XiKqQ8uEL-hC4ABeH6o9EsNVu7mGr0Uqm-Ox1BriQMh6kWv7JxooDA4fBEMi2v4luxAw3pjrY-5IByDNyMA4AeQA0kyAHJwABiLybW0ETfbByZAA0DowngA6afl+6UCF+0ulgDaAF1F0uIdw-hR4dViSUcptZeIWABHZDASN6YwASSrXQWGmW2jgAHFimsINQwuhSWc5kJU1bgZRNbGAPI3FEMYCBkeFERfHQvx-XAdBpP5RAsdA3A8LxRF8cUeGwVAAE8ogiKIYnEbxPzoFD0HpQ03A-GBkN-UkhS-EBgAwPY2NQjMs2KFNVjobiMEnFhUAgXAUhrOBMKKBsACkIEMcQABEIHQRh5z3QJkQsMBUOmTk4F6fojB0GQ6CgLhhg8XN0BY-idGDBIFWkZUvFVdVSi1Rx-ho1i6N-LceAc+AMAjfIXNCkz3LQZzaO-X9A24LhooxPI4tS1D5IgtwAEY9LgQI9gAWiq55DGsqBbK4IA)?

---

I'm migrating from ES6 to TypeScript and I'm getting an error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)` trying to rewrite a function for hook creation.

The original problem is simple: wrap an API method so I don't need to pass access token on every call.

All the methods which require an authorization token does have the same parent interface:

```js
export interface AuthParams {
    token: string;
}
```

A trivial example of the API method:

```js
interface GetProfileParams extends AuthParams {
    id: number;
}
interface Profile {
    name: string;
}

async function getProfile(params: GetProfileParams): Promise<Profile> {
    return Promise.resolve({ name: 'John Doe' });
}
```

I've implemented the function which can create a hook from any API method which requires authorization token. A hook consumes the token from [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and binds it as a method's default value of the 'token' parameter:

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';

interface PrivateMethod<TParams extends AuthParams, TResult> {
    (params: TParams): TResult;
}

interface SecuredMethod<TParams extends AuthParams, TResult> {
    (params: Exclude<TParams, AuthParams>): TResult;
}

function createAuthorizedMethodHook<
    TParams extends AuthParams,
    TResult
>(
    method: PrivateMethod<TParams, TResult>,
): () => SecuredMethod<TParams, TResult> {
    return () => {
        return useCallback(
            params => method({ token: 'TOKEN FROM CONTEXT', ...params }),
            [],
        );
    };
}
```

Lastly, I try to use function's wrapper and get an error:

```js
const useGetProfile = createAuthorizedMethodHook(getProfile);

const securedGetProfile = useGetProfile();

securedGetProfile({ id: 1 });
//                  ^^
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

Why do I get this error? Is it a bug? Should I create an issue at the [TypeScript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript)?

Tested on Typescript version `3.7.4` and `3.8.0-dev.20200115`.

Comment: Please do post the error in the question itself.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar I did that twice.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem myself.

I used TypeScript's `Extract` utility incorrectly.

The [correction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCBDANrgI2wGMBrOAXzgDMoIQ4ByKdEmRgbgCguB6XuJnogIAOzjBRMdFGol0XdAA9IsCVJlzi6OAEFkMABYAFbFGwhUiLnFtwYEUulEAuOKhhRJAc24Ue-HAAqjDAuDTIosShYvYQcMRiAG4y8NgGhtDAAF7oACZwIOhGEAUOcJmOfAK2LDDIUKI+CQ1e+YXFmQUA7sBGcU7iiaKoyEUFtPQJYtJKMFyS0rLycMZeSdjSALKdpQA8ACqm5pZwytKieVb6RscWqAA0cAcASuijuDAAfNZ2cAAUYDM9zcR2BlgAlKC3h8YH4eItNCsAMroYgNfI7Ep5Q53U7nZxXPQZPGPZ4w5CfH4IGx2QHg1BuADyID6uIZTycAE8INRibcGV8oeT3pS4Vx-FxqJFosBYsQWJt0DdMl5cnksV0ABIQRx7Wm2MEnKwEy7XEkcg0i2FcL7-K1FbFuNbADbbXY4o33J6vUVUh5cYX-CFwAC8P1R6JYGo97ONPopVN+djqDXEwbD1Ktf1TjRQGBw+CIZHtfzLdiBxszHWx-yQDkGbkYByZAGkAKIAOTgADEXkytoImZ2Du2ABoHRhPAB0s8r90ocGwVi9kID5fLAG0ALrrjcQ7h-Cjw6r8zI5TZy8QsACOyGA0b0xgAkjWugsNMttHAAOLFNa8mE6CkmccyEuaApVjSfzAHkbiiGMBAyPCiJfjoAHUEBya2KIFjoG4HheKIvgSjwy5clEERRDE4jeP+dCYbg6D0sabh-jAGFAaSwoAayGB7JxTFZjmxRpqsdB8eg04sKgEC4CkdZwLhRRNgAUhAhjiAAIhA6CMJQB6kaeyIWGATHTHkOi9P0Rg6DIdBQFwwwePm6DsYJOihgkirSCqWTqpqpQ6o4-x0RxDFAYZTliC5GBRvk7kReZXloG59GAUxwbcFwcUYnkiUZcxSCwW4ACMBkcHAgR7AAtHVzyGHZUAOVwQA):

```js
interface SecuredMethod<TParams extends AuthParams, TResult> {
    (params: Omit<TParams, keyof AuthParams>): TResult;
}
```

```js
params => method({ token: 'TOKEN FROM CONTEXT', ...params } as TParams)
```